# Using Storable to store hash and use it in another script

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I am storing a hash in a script like so (part of code left out):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;

use Storable qw(nstore_fd);

open( my $fh, ">",  'hash.hash');
my $hash_ref = \%hash;
nstore_fd($hash_ref, $fh);
close $fh;
```

Which creates a file `hash.hash`. In another file, then, I try to 'import' the hash and read its values to be used (e.g. looping the hash, reading values, checking existence ...).

I tried something simple, i.e. read the hash, dereference and read its keys, and print those out. However I get the error `Not a HASH reference at CreateSql.pl line 12.` It is a scalar. But I don't see why. [The documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) of the module states that a reference is returned.

> To retrieve data stored to disk, use retrieve with a file name. The
>   objects stored into that file are recreated into memory for you, and a
>   reference to the root object is returned.

So what did I do wrong, and how do I get access to the stored hash?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;

use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw(retrieve);

my ($hash_path) = @ARGV;

my $hash_ref = retrieve($hash_path);

my @keys = keys % { $hash_ref }; # throws error
print Dumper(\@keys);
```

Comment: I would also urge - don't use Storable to store stuff. There's open formats that are generally better because they're portable, like JSON or YAML. (XML perhaps, but only if you actually need the functionality of XML, which is overkill for _most_ applications)

Comment: @Sobrique The only goal of the stored hash is to be used in another script. Even in such a case, do you think it is better to encode as JSON in the first script, and then read JSON in a new hash in the second script? I don't know a lot about storage and efficiency, but speed wise this seems not very efficient. The data will never be used outside these two scripts, so I don't think a universal data type is required. What do you think, considering efficiency of the scripts?

Comment: Unless your data is huge, it makes marginal amounts of difference. If your data is huge, then dumping the data structure this way is not a great plan anyway. For interoperability, support and diagnostics, the human readable options IMO are just better for style reasons.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Sobrique ...although `Storable` is great, I have run into issues in the past across different versions of the distribution. `JSON` is just as easy or easier to use, and it's format is a very consistent standard. It's also cross-language. Also, "The data will never be used outside these two scripts"... I always assume the opposite, just to be safe.

Comment: Re "*but speed wise this seems not very efficient*", I don't see why it wouldn't be efficient. JSON is extremely simple to parse.

Comment: @ikegami I thought that because of the sheer size the encoding / parsing process would take up too much time. But because so many of you are suggesting this, I'll be using JSON. Thanks.

Comment: What size are you talking about? The parser would be extremely tiny due to the simplicity I just mentioned. (YAML would be another good choice if JSON is too limiting.)

Comment: @ikegami The data I'm working with would result in a hash of around 17 million keys. Luckily I've found a way to split this up in smaller chunks that still make sense in the global data structure.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to what we were discussing.

Comment: @ikegami You asked 'what size are you talking about', well, a hash of around 17 million keys.

Comment: Yes, and I don't know why you think that has anything to do with efficiency

Comment: @ikegami The larger the hash, the longer it'd take to encode/decode it to/from JSON, no? Chunking it up makes it (in the whole picture) more manageable and efficient for me.

Comment: What are you talking about??? First of all, we were trying to appease your reservations about using JSON. If JSON is faster than Storable, then the larger the hash, the more time you save by switching to JSON. Secondly, why do you pretend were talking about chunking? What does that even mean? If you're planning on splitting the data across multiple files, then you will be *slowing* things down by adding overhead.

Comment: @ikegami Calm down, I think you misinterpreted what I was trying to convey. You explained that JSON would be a good choice, and I accepted that as I said. I will be using JSON. However, due to the size of the hash (17 million+) and the structure of my input data (multiple files), I'll be outputting JSON for each file. Because I'll need those input files and those JSON files both in script 2, it's easy to have a 1-on-1 relation between JSON and input. I'll take the overhead, in turn for easier data management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really must show the code that has given you the problems that you describe, otherwise it becomes very hard to help you. The code in your question doesn't compile. If you want to make changes to the program before you publish it, the *test it again* to make sure that it at least compiles, and also display the problems you're reporting

The main problem is that you are writing binary data to a file opened as text. If you change `open( my $fh, ">",  'hash.hash')` to `open( my $fh, ">:raw",  'hash.hash')` then everything should work

This variant of your own code correctly stores and retrieves some sample data

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Storable qw/ nstore_fd retrieve /;

use constant STORAGE => 'hash.hash';

my %hash = ( a => 'b', c => 'd' );

{
    open my $fh, '>:raw',  STORAGE or die $!;
    nstore_fd \%hash, $fh;
}

my $hash_ref = retrieve STORAGE;

use Data::Dump;

dd $hash_ref;

my @keys = keys % { $hash_ref }; # throws error
dd \@keys;
```

#### output

```
{ a => "b", c => "d" }
["a", "c"]
```

However, you've made some strange choices. There's no need to use an `nstore` function to store the data in "network order", and you could have avoided the problem altogether if you had let the module open the file itself

Here's a variant that just uses `store` and `retrieve`. The output is identical to that of the code above

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Storable qw/ store retrieve /;

use constant STORAGE => 'hash.hash';

my %hash = ( a => 'b', c => 'd' );

store \%hash, STORAGE;

my $hash_ref = retrieve STORAGE;

use Data::Dump;

dd $hash_ref;

my @keys = keys % { $hash_ref }; # throws error
dd \@keys;
```

Comment: Well, no. The first part doesn't compile because I left out a bunch - as I clearly stated. It seemed to me (correctly so) that the error was in the code that I showed, which has nothing to do with any other code I could've provided. The problem was fixed by using `:raw`. Thanks. (Not sure why the question desever a down vote though.) Network store wasn't necessary indeed. But I do need `store_fd` because I am writing to the (already opened) file in multiple places in the script. At least that's how I understand that option.

Comment: @BramVanroy: One of the reason's to vote to close a question is "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**." (Emphasis original.) So you are in line for a close vote instead of just a down vote. You had no idea where the issue was, and you should have published a working example that displayed the same issue. Please also read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BramVanroy:  *"I do need store_fd because I am writing to the (already opened) file in multiple places in the script"*  In that case you need to use `fd_retrieve` instead. `retrieve` will repeatedly fetch the first data structure stored.

Comment: If those two scripts communicate through the file, maybe a file is not the right option. How about using a socket instead?